# Scanner skipping inputs?

Tags: java

I've been debugging the following program from hours yet I cannot find why is the sanner not taking the input for the field **name**

This is my source code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student
{
int rollNo;
String name;
double percentageMarks;
static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public void accept()
{
    System.out.print("Enter roll no: ");
    rollNo = input.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
    name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter percentageMarks: ");
    percentageMarks = input.nextDouble();
}

public void display()
{
    System.out.println("Name: " +name);
    System.out.println("roll no: " +rollNo);
    System.out.println("Percentage marks: " +percentageMarks);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Student s1 = new Student(), s2 = new Student();

    s1.accept();
    s2.accept();

    if(s1.percentageMarks>s2.percentageMarks)
        s1.display();
    else if (s2.percentageMarks>s1.percentageMarks)
        s2.display();
    else
        System.out.println("Both students has same marks");
}
}
```

This is an output sample:

```
Enter roll no: 1
Enter Name: Enter percentageMarks:
```

As seen, without it allowing to enter student name, its prompting to enter student percentage marks.

Any suggestion please?

Comment: You can read this post I wrote to clarify your doubts about this problem: [Using `nextInt()` before `nextLine()`](https://christprogramming.wordpress.com/2014/01/30/java-common-mistakes-1/)

Comment: Probably the scanner taking the newline (from pressing Enter) as input and thus skipping to the next input line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you first have the `input.nextInt()` and after it is finished it is not going to the next line. Just parse the whole first line as `Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine())` and you will get your input for the name after that.